# Stripe Checkout doesn't load 3D Secure

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

My websites Stripe Checkout doesn't load the credit card 3D Secure popup.

I get this error in the console:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a
> resource at eval (“script-src”). blob:27:22

Everything else works fine though. And it works in "Test Mode", even with the Stripe test card which requires authentication (4000 0027 6000 3184).

I'm using React and NextJS.
I have not edited the "Content Security Policy".
But even if i set the CSP to `default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` it still doesn't work.

[image: Stripe Checkout error]

Comment: This appears to be an issue between Stripe's inner 3DS iframe and Danske bank's 3DS page. Not much you can do about this, I recommend reaching out to Stripe support to let them know: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Thanks @PaulAsjes. This was their response:

Shedding light on it, this is a web development issue wherein it is outside our scope.
In addition to it, CSP is a Content Security Policy and its an issue relating to your servers and your policy is specific on your end. I wish we could offer more inputs on this however, we have no way of seeing it or troubleshooting it.
I went beyond and checked what option you can do, if you’re using mozilla you could test your CSP. But it's so far outside our wheelhouse we really can't offer any more advice than to test it to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Now it is working again.

It seems like it was an issue with 3D secure popup window from "Danske Bank" (the biggest bank in Denmark) as well as other banks I tested.
Now the bank must've fixed it.

I was I contact with Stripe support several times. Amongst other things, they said:
*"When it comes to the modal that appears, we actually have very little control over this as it is being hosted by the bank."*

So it seems like 3D secure is still just quite unstable or not well developed.